# Starting multiple Windows services if stopped

Tags: windows, powershell

I've tried the following few bits and i'm trying to create a function to insert into another powershell script

```
function start-OService{
Get-Service service1|?{$_.Status -eq 'Stopped'}|Start-Service
Get-Service service2|?{$_.Status -eq 'Stopped'}|Start-Service
}
```

And this one ...

```
function start-OService {
$services = 'service1', 'service1'

Get-Service | ? {
$services -contains $_.Name -and $_.Status -eq 'Stopped'
} | Start-Service

}
```

The first snippet doesn't seem to run correctly but i'm not getting an error. I can run each line individually but not the way I have it setup. 
The 2nd one was my original attempt that was taken from another SO question. The `Get-Service` doesn't seem to like the `$services` variable having multiple services contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function start-OService {
$services = 'service1', 'service1'

    foreach ($service in $services)
    {
        if ((Get-Service $service).Status -eq "Stopped")
        {
        Start-Service $service
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Tried this - nothing appears to happen. I've got both 'stopped' and they don't start, or when I try with one 'stopped'

Comment: oops, got it. Typo on my end!

Comment: One liner: "service1", "service2" | Get-Service | ?{ $_.Status -eq "Stopped" } | Start-Service

Comment: just wanted to keep the OP Structure, so it will be easier for him to understand

Answer (score 1):

One liner:

```
"service1", "service2" | Get-Service | ?{ $_.Status -eq "Stopped" } | Start-Service
```

Answer (score 0):

For starting all the services which was stopped at a given time, below script will be helpful

```
$StoppedServices=Get-Service | where {$_.Status -eq "Stopped"}
foreach ($item in $StoppedServices)
{
$Name=$item.Name
    Start-Service -Name $Name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function start-OService {
$services = 'service1', 'service1'

    $services | % {
        $service =  get-service -name $_;
        if($service.Status -eq [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]::Stopped)
        {
            Write-Output "Starting $_"
            $service.Start()
        }
    }
}
```